# Viewswitcher for two layouts

Tags: android, viewswitcher

I couldn't able to deal with viewswitcher. I want to have two buttons at the center top and center bottom. when we click the centertop button one view should translate from top to bottom and  reverse should possible when we click centerbottom button, There should be only two views, plese share  your knowledge with me coz I am new to android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two different xml layout files,one with forward and one with reverse layout of the previous one.
On pressing upper button,call the first xml file in setContentview method and on pressing the bottom button, call the other one.